# Swift Delegate Pattern: Delegate = Nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I know that this question has been asked a lot here and I've read all of them, but my problem is still persistent. I wanted to include the delegate pattern in my project in order to call a function in another class from one class. But it didn't work there either. So I created a completely new project to practice the pattern again. Only for 3 hours I just can't do it. My delegate still stays in my main ViewController nil.

This is my Code of my ViewController. It is the initialised ViewController and also the master of the delegate pattern, and the buttonViewController is the servant:

```
import UIKit

protocol ViewControllerDelegate {
    func printTest(message: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    }
    

    @IBAction func perform(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc") as! ButtonViewController
        if delegate == nil {
            print("Ist nil")
        }
        delegate?.printTest(message: "Test")
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

I would like to call a function in my buttonViewController if the user presses the perform button and than i want to perform a segue to my buttonViewController.

This is my ButtonViewController:

```
import UIKit


class ButtonViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ViewController().delegate = self
        print("test")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
    
    @IBAction func performsegue(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    func printTest(message: String) {
        print(message + "\(self)")
    }
}
```

I've already tried to perform a segue that first viewDidLoad is called by my ButtonViewController, then to go back to the ViewController and then call the perform method again via a button to then see whether delegate is still nil, and yes it was unfortunately still nil.

Can somebody help me with this Problem?

Best regards!

Comment: check this tutorial:  https://medium.com/@astitv96/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-delegate-and-protocol-ios-swift-4-beginners-e32828862d3f

Comment: The problem is that `ViewController().delegate = self` is a nonsense statement. It creates a new instance of `ViewController`, assigns `delegate` to it, and then discards it. That instance is never used.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a delegate here? From what I understand, you just want to do `vc.printTest(message: "Test")` in `perform`, so just do that!

Comment: @Sulthan I already thought about it, but it doesn't work even if I define my ViewController outside of viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Sweeper it´s just a test, After the test i want to change a picture in my buttonViewController.

Comment: Sulthan found exactly why your delegate cannot possible work.

Answer (score 3):

The delegate pattern is confusing at first for a lot of people.  I find that most of my students tend to try and do it backward at first, which is I think what is going on here as well.  Usually in the delegate pattern there is one view controller (A) that presents another (B).  Typically some action on B should trigger some function on A (in your case, perhaps a button press on B triggers causes A to print something).

In this scenario you would have two subclasses of `UIViewController`: `AViewController` and `BViewController` and a protocol `BViewControllerDelegate`.  It would be setup as follows:

1. The protocol `BViewControllerDelegate` would have the function you want to be called on `AViewController` when the button in `BViewController` is pressed.
2. `AViewController` would conform to this protocol and implement this function.
3. In `BViewController` you would have your delegate property defined: `weak var delegate: BViewControllerDelegate?`.
4. This property would be set on an instance of `BViewController` by  an instance of `AViewController` to itself (the instance of `AViewController`) during the presentation of `BViewController`.
5. The instance of `BViewController` would invoke the function on its delegate property in response to a button press.

```swift
class AViewController: UIViewController, BViewControllerDelegate {
    // This is 4, this segue action is invoked by a storyboard segue in the storyboard and is responsible for setting up the destination view controller and configuring it as needed (i.e., setting its delegate property)
    @IBSegueAction func makeBViewController(_ coder: NSCoder) -> BViewController {
        let bViewController = BViewController(coder: coder)!
        bViewController.delegate = self
        
        return bViewController
    }

    // Here we accomplish 2 (and also above where we declare conformance to the protocol)    
    func bViewControllerDidPerformAction(viewController: BViewController, message: String) {
        print(message)
    }
}
```

```swift
protocol BViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    // Here we accomplish 1
    func bViewControllerDidPerformAction(viewController: BViewController, message: String)
}

class BViewController: UIViewController {
    // Here is 5
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.bViewControllerDidPerformAction(viewController: self, message: "Test Message")
    }
    
    // This is 3
    weak var delegate: BViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do in your code, but I believe your `ViewController` should be setup like `AViewController` and your `ButtonViewController` should be setup like `BViewController`.  Also, the line of code `ViewController().delegate = self` does nothing, because it creates a new instance of `ViewController` and sets its delegate, but this new instance is immediately deallocated because it is not actually the one being used anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Protocol / Delegate pattern is used to allow an instantiated controller (or other object) to communicate back to the class that created it.

So, in your scenario, you want `ViewController` to conform to `ViewControllerDelegate` ... when you instantiate `ButtonViewController` (which has a `ViewControllerDelegate` delegate var), you assign that `ButtonViewController`'s delegate to self (`ViewController`).

Now, `ButtonViewController` can call protocol functions via its `delegate`.

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate {
    func printTest(message: String)
}

// make ViewController conform to ViewControllerDelegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func perform(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc") as! ButtonViewController
        
        // set self as the delegate in ButtonViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func printTest(message: String) {
        print("printTest in delegate:", message)
    }
    
}

class ButtonViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("test")
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // call the delegate
        delegate?.printTest(message: "Sending to delegate!")
    }

}
```

---

**Edit** -- here is a complete example to run. "Main" view controller has a button and a label. Tap the button to present the ButtonVC. Button view controller has a text field and a "Save and Close" button. Enter some text in the text field, tap the Save button, and the text will be sent to the Main controller via the `ViewControllerDelegate`.

No `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections needed -- just assign a blank view controller's custom class to `ViewController`:

```
// make ViewController conform to ViewControllerDelegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {
    
    let btn: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.setTitle("Show Button VC", for: [])
        v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        return v
    }()
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "From ButtonVC:\n"
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [label, btn].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showButtonsVC(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func showButtonsVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // instantiate Button View Controller
        let vc = ButtonViewController()
        
        // set self as the delegate in ButtonViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        
        // present it
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func printTest(message: String) {
        print("Delegate received:", message)
        label.text = "From ButtonVC:\n" + message
    }
    
}

class ButtonViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let v = UITextField()
        v.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        return v
    }()
    let btn: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.setTitle("Save and Close", for: [])
        v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        [textField, btn].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // call the delegate
        let str = textField.text ?? "No text entered..."
        delegate?.printTest(message: str)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @BenPython - ok, hard to know what to say without additional info on what "didn't work." I edited my answer with a complete, working example that you can run.